# Updating Rows in IQueryable and Save Changes

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core

I am trying to update all rows in IQueryable, that I retrieve from a database.

Is this the correct way to conduct this? When I run an Xunit test on this, the rows seem disappear.

```
foreach (var item in productCustomer)  // productCustomer is IQueryable
{
    item.isActiveStatus = (item.ExpirationYear < 2019);
}
_dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Currently using EF Core 3.1

Note: Trying to refrain from creating totally new object or remapping everything; just want to update 1 member out of the 20 members.

Comment: What is the previous logic of query?

Comment: Then you probably have a global query filter. That said, there's very little info to say anything more to the point.

Comment: This method of updating is very inefficient (however, as well as the EF as a whole). It will generate one SELECT query and many UPDATE queries. While you can do with a single UPDATE query.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

change

```
> foreach (var item in productCustomer)
```

to

```
foreach (var item in productCustomer.ToList())
```

IQueryable is nothing more that a select statement on the table that triggers a database read.
No object is stored in memory until you pull it into a List or whatever datatype makes the most sense for you.

Comment: Sorry, but none of this is true. The `foreach` statement forces execution of the `IQueryable` and the objects are stored in EF's change tracker, i.e. in memory (provided that there's no `AsNoTracking()` call). If OP thinks `ToList` fixed it, they probably *also* changed something else. The question is highly unclear, "the rows seem disappear" is a very vague statement.

Comment: Hint: the appropriate action here would be to delete the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first get the objects, before they can be tracked for changes. However, if all you're doing with the IQueryable is to update a member without touching anything else, it would be faster to just execute the UPDATE query.

Consider:

```
using(var context = new SampleContext())
{
    var commandText = "UPDATE Categories SET IsActiveStatus = ExpirationYear < 2019 --WHERE <YOUR CONDITIONS>";
    //var name = new SqlParameter("@variable", "value");
    context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(commandText/*,<params SqlParameter[]>*/);
}
```

Comment: "IQueryable doesn't do updates". No, but OP's code does do updates because they do "first get the objects".